# Compositeness test for Wagstaff numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

Is this proof acceptable ?

**Definition**

Let $W_p=\frac{2^p+1}{3} $ with $p$ prime and $p>3$ .

**Theorem**

If $W_p$ is prime then $7^{\frac{W_p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod {W_p}$

**Proof**

Let $W_p$ be a prime , then by Euler's criterion :

$7^{\frac{W_p-1}{2}} \equiv \left(\frac{7}{W_p}\right) \pmod {W_p}$ , where $\left(\frac{7}{W_p}\right)$ denotes Legendre symbol .

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 6$  then $W_p \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ and if $p \equiv 5 \pmod 6$  then $W_p \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ .

In both cases it follows that $\left(\frac{W_p}{7}\right)=1$ .

Since $W_p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ according to the law of quadratic reciprocity we have : $\left(\frac{7}{W_p}\right)=-1$ .

Hence ,  $7^{\frac{W_p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod {W_p}$

Comment: Looks perfect to me!